# Error 2607, "error LNK1104: cannot open file"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gpib

I have written C++ code in Visual Studio 2010 using NI GPIB version 4.61 and added all the libraries required by the code, but it is giving an error related to ".obj" file. Although I have added .CPP file of the same code and the header file related to this.

```
Error   2607    error LNK1104: cannot open file '%NIEXTCCOMPILERSUPP%\lib32\msvc\ni4882.obj'    D:\F1Nh-TESTER-2014-08-04\PUMA_LED_TESTER\PUMA_LED_TESTER\LINK  PUMA_LED_TESTER
```

I have seen lots of solutions for the same question, but nothing worked for me. I have added double quotes (" ") to the path of the library in linker as I saw in a solution on Stack Overflow. 
How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try *[Why do I get a linker error (LNK 2019) when using NI-488.2 driver in Microsoft Visual C\C++?](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/8994674C70A9147A862575B40055C5EA)* (National Instruments knowledge base).

Among other things, it suggest this:

> Include the object file in your project by adding the ni4882.obj object file to your project

and

> Complete the following steps to include the file in the linker options

1. In Visual Studio open Project » Properties.
2. Select linker in the tree diagram.
3. On the command line, enter %NIEXTCCOMPILERSUPP%\lib32\msvc\ni4882.obj. This environment variable points at the external compiler support folder.